# Howto execute a success action tied to inbound flow after message processing via DirectChannel

Tags: spring-integration

This question is more of a design question than a real problem. Given following basic flow:

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel getFileToSftpChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow sftpOutboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(getFileToSftpChannel())
                .handle(Sftp.outboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                                .useTemporaryFileName(false)
                                .remoteDirectory("test")).get();
    }
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow filePollingInboundFlow() {
    return from(s -> s.file(new File("path")).patternFilter("*.ext"),
            e -> e.poller(fixedDelay(60, SECONDS).channel(getFileToSftpChannel()).get();
}
```

There is an inbound file polling flow which publishes messages via a DirectChannel to an outbound SFTP flow uploading the file.
After the entire flow finishes, I want to execute a "success" action: move the original file (locally) to an archive folder.
Using the DirectChannel, I understand that the upload will happen in the same thread as the file polling.
In other words, the file poller blocks untill the upload completes (or an error message is returned which is then pushed to the error channel).
Knowing this, I want to place the 'success' action (= moving the original file) on the inbound flow. Things I already know about and don't want to use:

- Another 'handle' on the sftpOutbound. Reason: moving the file is tied to the inboud flow not the outbound flow. For ex. if I would introduce another, 2nd, producer later on (eg. a JMS inbound flow) publishing to the same channel, there would be no 'file' to be moved.
- Adding an interceptor on the DirectChannel and use the 'afterSendCompletion'. Reason: same as above, I want to logic to be tied to the inbound flow
- Add transaction semantics on the inbound flow and react on 'commit'. Reason: as all of this is non transactional (file system/SFTP based) I want to avoid using this.

Another thing I tried was adding an 'handle' on the inbound flow. However, I learned as the inbound flow has no real 'reply', the handle is executed before the message is sent, so this doesn't work as the move has to be executed after successful processing of the message.

Question in short: what is the standard way of executing an action supplied by the producer (=inbound flow) after the message was successfully processed by a consumer (=outbound flow) via the DirectChannel?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the standard way to do something similar is `transaction` and that's why we some time ago introduced the `PseudoTransactionManager` and the XML sample for similar task looks like:

```
<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="realTx" channel="txInput" auto-startup="false"
                         directory="${java.io.tmpdir}/si-test2">
    <int:poller fixed-rate="500">
        <int:transactional synchronization-factory="syncFactory"/>
    </int:poller>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.integration.transaction.PseudoTransactionManager"/>

<int:transaction-synchronization-factory id="syncFactory">
    <int:after-commit expression="payload.delete()"/>
</int:transaction-synchronization-factory>
```

As you see we remove the file in the end of transaction which is caused really after your move to SFTP.

I'd say it is the best way to be tied with only the producer.

Another way is to introduce one more channel before `getFileToSftpChannel()` and apply the `ChannelInterceptor.afterSendCompletion` which will be invoked in the end too, by the same single-thread reason. With this approach you should just `bridge` all your producers with their specific `DirectChannel`s to that single `getFileToSftpChannel()` for the SFTP adapter.

So, it's up to you what to choose. You have good argument from the architectural perspective to divide the logic by the responsibility levels, but as you see there is no so much choice...

Any other ideas are welcome!

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try  with the pseudo tx manager. A suggestion if feasible: maybe a success handler or 'after send completion' on the producer as well? Like:    `return from(s -> s.file(new File("path")).patternFilter("*.ext"),
            e -> e.poller(fixedDelay(60, SECONDS).channel(getFileToSftpChannel()).onSendSuccess(.......).get()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel getFileToSftpChannel() {
DirectChannel directChannel = new DirectChannel();
directChannel.addInterceptor(new ChannelInterceptorAdapter() {
@Override
public void afterSendCompletion(final Message<?> message, 
final MessageChannel channel, final boolean sent, final Exception ex) {
if (ex == null) {
new Archiver().archive((File) message.getPayload());
}
}
});
return directChannel;
}
```